# LINQ where query which matches both entries in a dictionary

Tags: c#

Struggling to get my head around this query and need a little help.

I have a List of items and I need to refine it down to a collection which meets two criteria.

For example

Collection of this class:

```
FakeClass
public int code { get; set;}
public int qty {get; set}
```

I have a list of items which I want to extract Which would be <code, qty>

I need to pull out all entries which match both the same code and qty

For example:

```
List<FakeClass> collection = {
{1, 1}
{2, 2}
{3, 1}
{1, 3}

List<int, int> to match
{1,1}
{1,2}
{1,3}
```

I only want to get 1,1 & 1,3 out of the collection.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You have 3 times the key `1` in your dictionary, which is impossible

Comment: `var result = collection.Where(x=> collection.Any(c=> c.Code == x.Code && c.Qty == x.Qty)).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cid has said, the Dictionary in your example isn't valid.  Assuming it was, best as I can tell from your example you just want something which filters the collection:

```
collection.Where(f => temp.containsKey(f.code) ? temp[f.code] == f.qty : false);
```